# Greek letter in hist3D

Tags: r, plot, graphics, tex

I'd like to plot a 3D histrogram with Greek letter using `hist3D`. I used the package `latex2exp` and `plot3D` My MWE is

```
test <- matrix(runif(100), ncol = 10)
plot3D::hist3D(z = test, bty = "g", phi = 15,  theta = -15,
               xlab = TeX("Polygonal vertices $(\\xi_1)$"), ylab = TeX("Polygonal vertices $(\\xi_2)$"), 
               zlab = "Frequency", main = "",
               col = "white", border = "black", shade = NULL, curtain = T, plot = T,
               ticktype = "detailed", space = 0.15, d = 2, cex.axis = 1e-9, image = T, contour = T)
```

Comment: This looks like a limitation of `plot3D::hist3D`:  the `TeX` function returns an expression, which R plot functions can usually handle fine, but `hist3D` converts it to a character vector before trying to plot it.  Maybe you should contact the `plot3D` maintainer to ask if this can be fixed:  it might be easy.

Comment: Actually it's also a problem in the base function `persp` (which `hist3D` calls to get the box and labels drawn), so it's not so easy to fix.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little tricky, but the function below will do it for you.  It is based on the `mtext3d` function in the `rgl` package, and you'll probably need to read the help page there to figure out how to use it.

```
library(plot3D)
library(latex2exp)

mtext3D <- function(text, edge, line = 0, at = NULL, pos = NA, ranges, trans,
                    adj = c(0.5, 0.5), ...)
{
  edge <- c(strsplit(edge, '')[[1]], '-', '-')[1:3]
  coord <- match(toupper(edge[1]), c('X', 'Y', 'Z')) 

  # Put the sign in the appropriate entry of edge
  if (coord == 2) edge[1] <- edge[2]
  else if (coord == 3) edge[1:2] <- edge[2:3]

  range <- ranges[[coord]]

  if (is.null(at)) at <- mean(range)

  newlen <- max(length(text),length(line),length(at))
  text <- rep(text, len = newlen)
  line <- rep(line, len = newlen)
  at <- rep(at, len = newlen)

  if (all(is.na(pos))) {
    pos <- matrix(NA,3,length(at))
    if (edge[1] == '+') pos[1,] <- ranges$x[2]
    else pos[1,] <- ranges$x[1]
    if (edge[2] == '+') pos[2,] <- ranges$y[2]
    else pos[2,] <- ranges$y[1]
    if (edge[3] == '+') pos[3,] <- ranges$z[2]
    else pos[3,] <- ranges$z[1]
  }
  else pos <- matrix(pos,3,length(at))
  pos[coord,] <- at
  ticksize <- 0.05*(pos[,1]-c(mean(ranges$x),mean(ranges$y),mean(ranges$z)))
  ticksize[coord] <- 0

  # Find rotation corresponding to box edge
  direction <- pos[, c(1,1), drop = FALSE]
  direction[coord, ] <- range
  xy <- trans3d(x = direction[1,], y = direction[2,], z = direction[3,], pmat = trans)
  srt <- atan2(diff(xy$y), diff(xy$x))    
  # Adjust rotation so text goes from left to right
  if (cos(srt) < 0) srt <- srt + pi

  text(trans3d(x = pos[1,]+3*ticksize[1]*line,
       y = pos[2,]+3*ticksize[2]*line,
       z = pos[3,]+3*ticksize[3]*line, trans),
       text, srt = srt * 180/pi, xpd = NA, ...)
} 

test <- matrix(runif(100), ncol = 10)
par(mar = c(10, 10, 10, 10)/2)
trans <- hist3D(z = test, bty = "g", phi = 15,  theta = -15,
               xlab = "", ylab = "", 
               zlab = "Frequency", main = "",
               col = "white", border = "black", shade = NULL, curtain = T, plot = T,
               ticktype = "detailed", space = 0.15, d = 2, cex.axis = 1e-9, image = T, contour = T)
ranges <- list(x = 0:1, y = 0:1, z = range(test))
mtext3D(TeX("Polygonal vertices $(\\xi_1)$"), "x--", line = 1.5, ranges = ranges, trans = trans)
mtext3D(TeX("Polygonal vertices $(\\xi_2)$"), "y--", line = 1.5, ranges = ranges, trans = trans)
```

The idea is that you draw your original plot with blank labels, then use `mtext3D` to add labels.  They can contain Greek or other special characters, just like other base plots.  Here's the result of the above example:

[image]